# Netty data streaming performance + websocket performance

Tags: performance, websocket, netty

I wanted to look at some particular performance numbers for netty and have looked over the various links in the [related articles section](https://netty.io/Main/Related+Articles) on the netty website.

But most of them talk about the number of simultaneous connections to a netty server and not about the **data transfer rate or something similar** which I wish to look over.

Also , any performance numbers **specifically for a netty websocket server** ? (I understand it may depend on the websocket protocol used as well to some extent , is it ?)

If someone has done some work / seen some links on the web in any of the 2 areas , could they please share some data numbers / insights ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run the AutoBahn tests against Netty. It includes some performance tests.

For instructions, see [here](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/master/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/http/websocketx/autobahn/package-info.java) for netty 4 and [here](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/3/src/main/java/org/jboss/netty/example/http/websocketx/autobahn/package-info.java) for netty 3.

Comment: shucks, the pages 404 now.

Answer (score 0):

Vague numbers are not going to be of much help here. The number of parameters involved is so large, that only a much more concrete case can give you reasonable numbers. What do you need to achieve? Maximum transfer speed you can test by sending the same byte (or block of bytes) again and again to an already connected client. That gives you an upper limit (for the hardware, OS and protocol stack versions and settings).